# Change "Opportunities" button name in navigation pane using Site Map

Tags: dynamics-crm, sitemap, dynamics-crm-2015

Is it possible that using the SiteMap to change the name of the Opportunity button that appears in the Sales navigation pane to any custom name instead of "Opportunities" ? Or this is a fixed name based on the name of the entity ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to change the display name of the opportunity entity.

[image]